# Incrementing integer stored in a file: Perl

Tags: perl

I have a file `tmp.txt` which contains only an integer `0`.

I need to read this file and increment it by 1.

```
open (my $tmp, '+<', $tmp_file) or die "failed to open";
flock($tmp, LOCK_EX);
$t_int = int(<$tmp>);
$t_count = $t_int + 1;
print "***********t_count in file $t_int , $t_count**********\n";
print $tmp $t_count;
print "===========t_count in file $t_int ,  $t_count==========\n";
close($tmp) or die "failed to close";
```

I get the output as follows:

Runnning script for the first time:

```
***********t_count in file 0 , 1**********
===========t_count in file 0 ,  1==========
```

Second time:

```
***********t_count in file 1 , 2**********
===========t_count in file 1 ,  2==========
```

Third time:

```
***********t_count in file 12 , 13**********
===========t_count in file 12 ,  13==========
```

Fourth time:

```
***********t_count in file 1213 , 1214**********
===========t_count in file 1213 ,  1214==========
```

Fifth time:

```
***********t_count in file 12131214 , 12131215**********
===========t_count in file 12131214 ,  12131215==========
```

and so on...

I don't understand why it is concatenating the previous numbers to the results. Why is this script not correct?

Comment: You're writing the new number at the position that the filehandle was in after you read the old number — i.e. the end of the file. You should seek back to the beginning.

Comment: What do you mean by "seek back to the beginning"? Do I have to close the file handle and reopen the file again to copy the result of `t_count`?

Comment: [perldoc -f seek](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/seek.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use seek to go back to the start of the file before you print to the file. Try adding this before you print:
`seek($tmp,0,0);`

Answer (score 4):

`seek()` allows you to move position in the filehandle.

`seek($fh, 0, SEEK_SET)` means move to the position zero bytes away from the start of the file. You have to import the constant from `Fcntl`.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Fcntl qw/ LOCK_EX SEEK_SET /;

my $tmp_file = 'test.dat';
open (my $tmp, '+<', $tmp_file) or die $!; 
flock($tmp, LOCK_EX);

my $t_int   = (int(<$tmp>));
my $t_count = $t_int + 1;

seek ($tmp, 0, SEEK_SET);
print $tmp $t_count;
close $tmp or die $!; 

__END__
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation :)

Answer (score 2):

This is much more convenient using the core module [`Tie::File`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Tie::File)

Here's an example of how it might work

```
use Tie::File;
use Fcntl 'LOCK_EX';

my $tmp_file = 'inc.txt';

{
    my $tied = tie my @file, 'Tie::File', $tmp_file or die $!;
    $tied->flock(LOCK_EX);
    ++$file[0];
}
```

---

#### Update

Because of the `flock` I assume this is to be run in parallel using something like [`Parallel::ForkManager`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Parallel::ForkManager). This program shows how to increment the number in the file 1,000 times using thirty parallel processes

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Tie::File;
use Fcntl 'LOCK_EX';
use Parallel::ForkManager;

my $tmp_file = 'inc.txt';

my $pm = Parallel::ForkManager->new(30);

for (1 .. 1000) {

    next if $pm->start;

    {
        my $tied = tie my @file, 'Tie::File', $tmp_file or die $!;
        $tied->flock(LOCK_EX);
        ++$file[0];
    }

    $pm->finish;
}

$pm->wait_all_children;
```